# Java different return type in a function respect to the header method

Tags: java, return, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 to parse my grammer and OWLAPI to work on ontologies. Since I'm using the Listener class I cannot modify the return type. Here an example:

```
public void exitSubConcept(Parser.SubConceptContext ctx) {
    OWLClassExpression first = stack.pop();
    OWLClassExpression second = stack.pop();
    OWLSubClassOfAxiom s = factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(second, first);
    if(reasoner.isEntailed(s))
    {
        System.out.println(s.toString() + "is entailed");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(s.toString() + "is NOT entailed");
    }
    super.exitSubConcept(ctx);
}
```

This is awful since the only thing I can return is a print, but I'm interested to provide a return type that is boolean (in this example), not just a print that I cannot manage.
**There is no way to modify the return type void because the parser crashes**, so do you have any particular suggestions to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: can you declare a boolean variable?

Comment: Yes. I just found a pretty solution that means declaring a boolean static variable and call it outside this function (and class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an instance boolean variable and use `hasEntailed()` to get the boolean value (I am using hasEntails for distinguish with the existing isEntailed() method)

```
private boolean entailed = false;

public boolean hasEntailed(){
    return entailed;
}

public void exitSubConcept(Parser.SubConceptContext ctx) {
    OWLClassExpression first = stack.pop();
    OWLClassExpression second = stack.pop();
    OWLSubClassOfAxiom s = factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(second, first);
    if(reasoner.isEntailed(s))
    {
        System.out.println(s.toString() + "is entailed");
        entailed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(s.toString() + "is NOT entailed");
        entailed = false;
    }
    super.exitSubConcept(ctx);
}
```